# How to schedule restart of web server on Basic tier?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have a web app running on a Basic Tier with logged in users.
The web server appears to restart randomly about once a day which interrupts these users.
How can I get the web server to restart overnight instead?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies it maybe be late response.

In most cases unexpected restart could happen due to unhandled exception originated in the chosen application framework (such as Python, Asp.Net, PHP etc.) and/or the application code.

Firstly, to understand why the restart occurred, you may leverage App Service diagnostics from Azure Portal>  navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal.

In the left navigation, click on Diagnose and solve problems – Checkout the tile for “Diagnostic Tools” > “Availability and Performance” > and “**Web App Restarted**” (to fetch more details).

To answer your question, you may create a **triggered WebJob task to restart** the WebApp. Is available on Basic App Service Plan.

See this doc section '[Create a scheduled WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON)' for more details.

[image: Web App Restarted]

Comment: Additionally,

------(if your requirement fits)
Auto-healing - you can auto detect certain conditions and automatically recover/restart.  Auto Heal feature which allows you to configure limits on your Web App for request count, slow requests, Http status codes, and memory usage.

-----
Proactive Auto Heal, the Web App that is taking up a lot of memory for example, would be restarted. If you have multiple instances, only the one in the bad state would be restarted.
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/17/Introducing-Proactive-Auto-Heal.html